# Destructor is re-running at Application exit

Tags: c++, destructor

I have this one class: say "`InterClass`".
This class is declared in say, `MainClass` as:

in `MainClass.h` :

```
public:
    InterClass *m_pInterClass;
```

and in Constructor of MainClass:

```
m_pInterClass = new InterClass(this);
```

I want to use some functions of MainClass in InterClass, so passing `this` in constructor. I assign this to a global pointer and use it everywhere in class.

In `main()` everything works fine until it reaches to end.

Last lines of my code are:

```
delete MainClass;
OutputDebugString("Exiting Application");
return 0;
```

My Application crashes at "`return 0`"
I put OutputDebugString() everywhere in my code.
What I narrowed down is:
On DebugView- 
 I can see Destructor of "InterClass" getting executred then "Exiting Application" and then again Destructor of "InterClass" executes.
I am confused why destructor of InterClass gets executed twice? that to at `return 0;`

I can't put breakpoint in this application due to nature of this application.

P.S. I am an Embedded C programmer and completely new to C++ (who is forced to work on PC application :( )

Comment: Can we see a small, complete sample of relevant parts?

Comment: Do you have a static instance of `InterClass` somewhere?

Comment: @J-16SDiZ No...No Static instance!

Comment: You don't need to post sensitive code; start from scratch or pare down and create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). The process will likely answer your question without our help…

Comment: @SwanandPurankar, Is it possible to just try it with small, fake classes that have the same effect? That's what we'd want to see.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Sorry... Updated the post!

Comment: Have you obeyed the [Rule Of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)?

Comment: As it stands, the question isn't really bad (anymore), so `+1` from me. If you indeed forgot to define a suitable copy constructor/assignment operator (see Rule of Three), you should _accept_ Als' answer. What book are you learning C++ for? (You cannot pick up C++ "on the go", you need to study thoroughly, preferably from a book.) Your terminology seems confused. (For example, there's no destructor called for a class, only for objects, which are instances of the class.) There's lots of _really_ bad books out there. You will need [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/140719).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, this smells of not obeying the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**.
Your class ***Copy constructor*** and ***Copy assignment operator*** should do a deep copy of the dynamically allocated member pointer. If not then you  are bound to see the behavior you get.

Either way you should avoid using a raw pointer member to being with.You are much better off wrapping it up in a **Smart pointer**.

Comment: Seems so! Let me Read about it!!

Comment: @sbi: I just saw your comment under the Q.From the timestamps,You concluded that before me :) so my +1.